# asking data from external device with selected delay using C#

Tags: c#

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
   string[] DF_Engines = { Form2.Engine1, Form2.Engine2, Form2.Engine3, Form2.Engine4, Form2.Engine5, Form2.Engine6 };
   foreach (string DF_Engine in DF_Engines)
   {
       if (Convert.ToDouble(DF_Engine) != 99)
       {
           string Hex_ADD1 = "{" + DF_Engine + "|";
           Console.WriteLine(Hex_ADD1);
           serialPort1.Write(Hex_ADD1);
           n = Convert.ToInt16(DF_Engine);               
        }
    }
}
```

`Form2.Engine1`, `Form2.Engine2`....... are the values come from `Form2` when the corresponding checkbox is selected. these would be 1, 2 , 3 so on....
My code send 01 when checkbox1 is selected but it send 01,02 without any delay when checkbox1 and checkbox2 are selected in Form2.
I need delay when asking 01 and 02 and so on as per my interest.
how could i do it convineintly
and when i use `Thread.Sleep(500)`, the application gets slow.
need guidance.

Comment: It looks like WinForms, but please just confirm this and add appropriate tag, so the question is tagged better :).

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a separate thread of just a `BackgroundWorker` control. This way, you could use `Thread.Sleep()` method and it should not make the application's GUI unresponsive. You can find some more information about it on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx.

Just add a `BackgroundWorker` control to your form and use this code to handle appropriate events:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] DF_Engines = { Form2.Engine1, Form2.Engine2, Form2.Engine3, Form2.Engine4, Form2.Engine5, Form2.Engine6 };

    //disable timer1, so it wont tick again until the current work is finished
    timer1.Stop();

    //start processing asynchronously, so GUI is still responsive
    sampleBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(DF_Engines);
}

//this method should be attached to DoWork event of the BackgroundWorker
private void sampleBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string[] DF_Engines = (e.Argument as string[]);

    foreach (string DF_Engine in DF_Engines)
    {
        if (Convert.ToDouble(DF_Engine) != 99)
        {
            string Hex_ADD1 = "{" + DF_Engine + "|";
            Console.WriteLine(Hex_ADD1);
            serialPort1.Write(Hex_ADD1);
            //n gets overwritten in each iteration, is this line required?
            n = Convert.ToInt16(DF_Engine);

            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }

    //you can also pass a result from this method back to the GUI thread like this
    //e.Result = "job done";
    //this can be read later in RunWorkerCompleted method of the BackgroundWorker
}

//this method should be attached to RunWorkerCompleted event of the BackgroundWorker
private void sampleBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //start timer1, so it can invoke the worker again
    timer1.Start();
}
```

If you need more help with this, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Thread.Sleep on UI thread. It will definitely slow down your application. Rather start a new thread, pass data to that thread and let that thread send input to your application with delay.

```
System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread((inputList) =>
    {
       foreach (var input in inputList as IEnumerable<int>)
       {
          //Send input
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
      });
  thread.Start();
```

Where inputList is an array of data(1,2,etc depending upon your checkbox selected).